# Limit when $y>>a$ of a derived solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, trigonometry, power-series

[image]

I am able to do part d), however I am very stuck on part e).

If $y >> a$ then surely we get

$\phi(x,y)$ $= \frac{1}{\pi} \Big[ tan^{-1} \Big( \frac{x+a}{y}\Big)-tan^{-1} \Big(\frac{x-a}{y}\Big)\Big] \rightarrow \frac{1}{\pi} \Big[ tan^{-1} \Big( \frac{x}{y}\Big)-tan^{-1} \Big(\frac{x}{y}\Big)\Big]=0$

which clearly is not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

The classical formulas are $$\tan ^{-1}(a)+\tan ^{-1}(b)=\tan ^{-1} \big( \frac {a+b}  {1-a~b}\big)$$  $$\tan ^{-1}(a)-\tan ^{-1}(b)=\tan ^{-1} \big( \frac {a-b}  {1+a~b}\big)$$

I am sure that you can take from here.